# Trying to parse json C#

Tags: c#, json

I have the following json:

```
[
{
"value1": 2,
"value2": [
  12
],
"value3": 10,
"value4": [
  1,2
],
"value5": null,
"value6": 0,
"value7": 1,
"value8": 2,
"value9": 3,
"value10": [
  "4"
],
"value11": false,
"value12": false,
"value13": 0,
"value14": "text\n",
"value15": 2,
"value16": 0,
"value17": 3,
"value18": 2,
"value19": 2,
"value20": 0,
"value21": 5,
"value22": "10.1",
"value23": "O",
"value24": 3,
"value25": 5,
"value26": 0,
"value27": null,
"value28": false,
"value29": "Net",
"value32": 14,
"value33": [
  "F",
  "M"
],
"value34": 0
},
{
"value1": 2,
"value2": [
  42
],
"value3": 1,
"value4": [

],
"value5": null,
"value6": 0,
"value7": 1,
"value8": 146,
"value9": 350,
"value10": [
  "other"
],
"value11": false,
"value12": false,
"value13": 0,
"value14": "F\n",
"value15": 1,
"value16": 0,
"value17": 3,
"value18": 1,
"value19": 1,
"value20": 0,
"value21": 5361,
"value22": "10.1",
"value23": "O",
"value24": 2,
"value25": 0,
"value26": 0,
"value27": null,
"value28": false,
"value29": null,
"value30": null,
"value31": "Net",
"value32": 146,
"value33": [
  "F"
],
"value34": 0
 }
]
```

And via Visual Studio Past special that build for me the following class:

```
 public class Rootobject
{
    public Class1[] Property1 { get; set; }
}

public class Class1
{
    public int value1 { get; set; }
    public int[] value2 { get; set; }
    public int value3 { get; set; }
    public object[] value4 { get; set; }
    public object value5 { get; set; }
    public int value6 { get; set; }
    public int value7 { get; set; }
    public int value8 { get; set; }
    public int value9 { get; set; }
    public string[] value10 { get; set; }
    public bool value11 { get; set; }
    public bool value12 { get; set; }
    public int value13 { get; set; }
    public string value14 { get; set; }
    public int value15 { get; set; }
    public int value16 { get; set; }
    public int value17 { get; set; }
    public int value18 { get; set; }
    public int value19 { get; set; }
    public int value20 { get; set; }
    public int value21 { get; set; }
    public string value22 { get; set; }
    public string value23 { get; set; }
    public int value24 { get; set; }
    public int value25 { get; set; }
    public int value26 { get; set; }
    public object value27 { get; set; }
    public bool value28 { get; set; }
    public string value29 { get; set; }
    public int value32 { get; set; }
    public string[] value33 { get; set; }
    public int value34 { get; set; }
    public object value30 { get; set; }
    public string value31 { get; set; }
}
```

Now, I'm tried to Deserialized the json text with the following code:

```
JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
Rootobject o= serializer.Deserialize<Rootobject>(objectString)
```

And i got the following exception:

> Type 'MyProj.Rootobject' is not supported for deserialization of an array.

What is my problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use following root object class

```
 public class RootObject
{
    public int value1 { get; set; }
    public List<int> value2 { get; set; }
    public int value3 { get; set; }
    public List<object> value4 { get; set; }
    public object value5 { get; set; }
    public int value6 { get; set; }
    public int value7 { get; set; }
    public int value8 { get; set; }
    public int value9 { get; set; }
    public List<string> value10 { get; set; }
    public bool value11 { get; set; }
    public bool value12 { get; set; }
    public int value13 { get; set; }
    public string value14 { get; set; }
    public int value15 { get; set; }
    public int value16 { get; set; }
    public int value17 { get; set; }
    public int value18 { get; set; }
    public int value19 { get; set; }
    public int value20 { get; set; }
    public int value21 { get; set; }
    public string value22 { get; set; }
    public string value23 { get; set; }
    public int value24 { get; set; }
    public int value25 { get; set; }
    public int value26 { get; set; }
    public object value27 { get; set; }
    public bool value28 { get; set; }
    public string value29 { get; set; }
    public int value32 { get; set; }
    public List<string> value33 { get; set; }
    public int value34 { get; set; }
    public object value30 { get; set; }
    public string value31 { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: its worked for me..Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
var o= serializer.Deserialize<List<Rootobject>>(objectString)
```

Comment: Hi, the list contains two elements but they are null both

Comment: Could you offer more detail?

Comment: I have no exception but the list elements is empty

Comment: @CSharpBeginner try Nikhil.Patel answer

Comment: Combine of two answers..thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

You can deserialize your json without `Rootobject` with using Newtonsoft.Json NuGet Package:

```
List<Class1> results = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IList<Class1>(objectString).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

First create the object of class and then try this

```
Rootobject rootobject = new Rootobject();

    string json = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(rootobject );
```